# Descobrir se um objeto timedelta tem algum atributo negativo

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tenho uma função que recebe um parâmetro do tipo `timedelta`. Estou buscando  por formas de saber se o objeto passado por parâmetro tem algum de seu atributos `(days=0, seconds=0, microseconds=0, milliseconds=0, minutes=0, hours=0, weeks=0)` negativo.
A solução que me veio a mente é fazer uma soma com a data/hora atuais, ou seja:

```
>>> dat = datetime.now()
>>> td = timedelta(days=-1)
>>> if (dat+td) < dat:
...   print('timedalta negativo')
... 
timedalta negativo
>>>
```

Porém não me agrada muito lógicas que estão "amarradas" ao calendário da máquina, pois dessa forma sua lógica está fortemente dependente de um fator externo.
A outra forma seria um `if` grande verificando um por um dos atributos.

Alguma terceira alternativa?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode testar o valor retornado por `.total_seconds()` no objeto timedelta. Se o valor for negativo, então o timedelta é negativo. Não há necessidade de se comparar com nenhuma data real.

```
>>> td = timedelta(days=-1)
>>> if td.total_seconds() < 0:
...     ...
```

Lembrando que um ojbeto "timedelta" é uma *duração de tempo* então ela é positiva, ou é negativa, e não faz sentido falar em "algum atributo negativo". Se eu crio um objeto timedelta de "2 dias e -4 horas", a duração total é de 1 dia e 20 horas, ou de 44 horas, ou esse número em segundos - não faz sentido querer ver se os ".seconds()"  são negativos, por partes.

Answer (score 0):

Se eu entedi o que vc está perguntando acho seu exemplo não funciona para detectar se tem algum "atributo" negativo, pelo menos não em python3. Python converte tudo para `days` e `seconds`, veja o exemplo abaixo:

```
import datetime

moment = datetime.datetime.now()
td = datetime.timedelta(weeks=1, days=-7, hours=24, minutes=360) 
td.__repr__()
'datetime.timedelta(days=1, seconds=21600)'

moment+td < moment
False
```

Veja que embora eu tenha atibuido um número negativo para o parametro `days`, a representação do objeto conta os dias em `weeks` e subtrai `days` que se torna zero, então o número em `hours` é convertido para 1 dia `days=1` e minutos são convertidos para sgundos (360*60) `seconds=21600`. Na verdade, com exceção de `days`, `seconds` e `microseconds`, todos os outros parametros relativos à atribuição de "tempo" são acessiveis somente para atribuição e composição dos outros três, se vc tentar "acessar" qualquer um deles vc obterá um erro. Voce pode verificar os atributos acessiveis de uma instancia de `timedelta` com a função `dir`, veja:

```
dir(datetime.timedelta)
Out[108]: 
['__abs__',
 '__add__',
 '__bool__',
 '__class__',
 '__delattr__',
 '__dir__',
 '__divmod__',
 '__doc__',
 '__eq__',
 '__floordiv__',
 '__format__',
 '__ge__',
 '__getattribute__',
 '__gt__',
 '__hash__',
 '__init__',
 '__init_subclass__',
 '__le__',
 '__lt__',
 '__mod__',
 '__mul__',
 '__ne__',
 '__neg__',
 '__new__',
 '__pos__',
 '__radd__',
 '__rdivmod__',
 '__reduce__',
 '__reduce_ex__',
 '__repr__',
 '__rfloordiv__',
 '__rmod__',
 '__rmul__',
 '__rsub__',
 '__rtruediv__',
 '__setattr__',
 '__sizeof__',
 '__str__',
 '__sub__',
 '__subclasshook__',
 '__truediv__',
 'days',
 'max',
 'microseconds',
 'min',
 'resolution',
 'seconds',
 'total_seconds']
```

Voce pode, também, "brincar" com isso da seguinte forma:

```
'days' in dir(td1)
True

'weeks' in dir(td1)
False

'minutes' in dir(td1)
False

'seconds' in dir(td1)
True
```

Sem conhecer o seu contexto, arrisco dizer que provavelmente voce terá que criar uma outra estratégia para lidar com o problema (novamente: se é que eu entendi), talvez ao invés de receber uma instancia de `timedelta`, um dicionario.

Comment: Na verdade é mais como o @jsbueno citou. Preciso saber se o timedelta é negativo ou positivo.